# Prove that $\phi(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ iff $n=2^k$ for some integer $k\geq 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> **Prove that $\phi(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ iff $n=2^k$ for some integer $k\geq 1$**

Attempt:
Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$. Then $\phi(n)=\frac{n}{2} \implies \frac{n}{2}=n(1-\frac{1}{p_1})(1-\frac{1}{p_2})\cdots (1-\frac{1}{p_k})$
$\implies p_1p_2\dots p_k=2(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots (p_k-1)$.

> **Unable to go further. Please help.**

The converse part:
 If $n=2^k$ then $\phi(n)=\phi(2^k)=2^k(1-1/2)=n/2.$ (proved)

Comment: yes, Thanks I have corrected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\phi(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ if and only if $n=2^k$ for some positive integer k](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171769/phin-fracn2-if-and-only-if-n-2k-for-some-positive-integer-k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Thomas's hint, and writing out the comments:

[Wikipedia on Euclid's Lemma:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

> If a prime divides the product of two numbers, it must divide at least one of those numbers.

I'll leave you to figure out why this can be applied to a product of more than two numbers.

$p_k$ is the largest prime factor, and it's a factor of 
$2(p_1−1)(p_2−1)⋯(p_k−1)$.

Euclid's lemma says it must divide at least one of them.  So which one does it divide?

Assume  $p_k > 2$. Then $p_k \nmid 2$

Does $p_k | (p_1-1)$?  $p_k | (p_2-1)$?  Etc.

For the other case, $p_k = 2$, the problem is over.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the solution. Now $p_k=max({p_i})=2$, then $p_i=2$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots k-1$. Then $n=p_1\dots p_k=2^k$. Is it not correct?

Comment: I don't know.  I'd have to look more closely at your entire argument to tell.  One thing that's throwing me off is that you use $k$ in several places in your argument, but I'm not sure you intend for it to be the same $k$.  Sorry I couldn't help you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $p_k$ be the largest prime factor. It is a factor of:

$$2(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots (p_k-1)$$

Comment: Please explain in details.

Comment: Sorry, that's it for today. This is a nearly complete hint.

Comment: @user1942348 but $p_k$ is co-prime to any $m$ if $m<p_k$, so $p_k-1 \dots p_1-1$ are all co-prime to $p_k$ so $p_k|2$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Not understand, would you please explain.

Comment: @user1942348: Let $p_k$ be the largest prime among $p_1,\dots,p_k$, so $p_i-1<p_k$ , so $(p_i-1,p_k)=1$ due to $p_k$ is a prime and $p_i-1<p_k$. So $((p_1-1)(p_2-1)\dots(p_k-1),p_k)=1$. But $p_k|2(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\dots(p_k-1)$ so $p_k|2$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Yes, that means, $p_k=2$. Also, I am not understand that why $p_k|2(p_1-1)\cdots(p_k-1)$

Comment: @user1942348 $p_k$ clearly divides LHS of $p_1p_2\dots p_k=2(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots (p_k-1)$, so it must divide the RHS, namely it must divide $2(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots (p_k-1)$. By [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $p_k$ (it is prime) thus divides $2$ or $p_1-1$ or $p_2-2$ or $\ldots$ or $p_k-1$. It can't divide neither of $p_1-1,p_2-1,\ldots, p_k-1$, because $p_k$ is larger than all of them. So $p_k$ must divide $2$. Since $p_k$ is a prime, $p_k=2$. $2$ is itself the least existing prime, while $p_k$ is the largest of $p_i$, so $k=1$.

Comment: @user1942348 ...and $2$ is the only possible prime divisor of $n$ (since you defined that $p_i$ are prime divisors of $n$).

Comment: Every time you guys comment here, I get a notification. It is okay to write a separate answer. Usually, considered polite to start it "Expanding on Thomas's hint..."

Answer (score 2):

Write $n$ as $n=2^km$, where $\gcd(m,2) = 1$. This gives us
$$\phi(n) = \phi(2^k) \phi(m) = 2^{k-1} \phi(m) \,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$
We are also given that
$$\phi(n) = \dfrac{n}2 = 2^{k-1}m \,\,\,\, (\clubsuit)$$
Comparing $(\spadesuit)$ and $(\clubsuit)$, we obtain that $\phi(m) = m$. This means $m=1$ is the only possibility, since for $m > 1$, we have $\phi(m) < m$. Hence, we obtain $n=2^k m$.